# Running schema recurring...Plugin class Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Pluginame doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, marketplace

On submitting module to  marketplace the Installation & Varnish Test Results failed stating  Running schema recurring...Plugin class Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\Pluginame doesn't exist but on my local machine its working fine. Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: did you tried to run command **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** to generate error?

Comment: Yes everything fine in local

Comment: if using window?the check for lower case problem.

Comment: No issue on my local machine its only issue when we submitted to magento marketplace. Do any prerequisites or steps to reproduce issue in local as I received in marketplace